# How to mention integration service name during importing workflow in a versioned repository from one environment to another

Tags: workflow, versioning, informatica-powercenter

Whenever I try to import a workflow from Dev/Test environment of a versioned repository into Production environment which is also versioned, I get a option where it asks me if I want to Check in or continue without check in. What happens if I do not check in and continue? Will all the objects used in the workflow will not be checked in or is it just the workflow which will not be checked in? I am asking this because, it will be double work if all the objects used will not be checked in including the Workflow, then, I have to go one by one to check in the objects. If I check the check in option for the workflow, after importing the Workflow, the integration service is left blank and when I run it, it is pointing towards the Integration service not mentioned error. For this I generally check out the workflow once I import just to mention the Integration service name. I do not think this is a good practice. Any advices on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dhruuv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will all the objects used in the workflow will not be checked in or is it just the workflow which will not be checked in?

The objects that will be left in the checked out state are:

- the workflow,
- the new objects (i.e. they were not present in the Prod repository before the import from Dev/Test),
- the modified objects (i.e. they were present in the Prod repository but were overwritten because you chose the *Replace* option).

> I have to go one by one to check in the objects

You don't have to check in every individual object - in *Repository Manager* open the *Versioning* menu and choose the *Find Checkouts...* option. All the checked out objects will be listed - you can select them and check in all of them at once.

Comment: What about mentioning the integration service name in the imported workflow. If I replace a workflow which already exists with the same name in the repository, then the integration service name is automatically taken from the previous version of the workflow. However, if I am importing a new workflow, is there a way to mention the prod integration service while importing itself?

Comment: @Dhruuv No, not that I am aware of. I always set IS manually in newly imported WFs.